# Chrome or Mac OS automatically deletes github diffs on download

Tags: google-chrome, git

I've been trying to save a simple GitHub PR diff to my downloads folder. The moment it saves, I can't open it because it vanishes and Chrome shows "removed" on the download.

[image: screenshot of download removed]

What could be causing this?

Comment: macOS isn't natively doing it.  Do you have a Folder Action configured on your Downloads folder that is moving them to some other location?  Do you have an application like Hazel that's moving files around for you?

Comment: Nope. I was able to create the file directly in the downloads folder by pasting into a new text file so it would seem to be the result of Chrome doing something.

Comment: Try the same thing with other browsers. If it is Chrome, I would remove it completely, rip *everything* out of your system related to Google. And then, if you must, reinstall it. But honestly I'd use Brave instead. It's Chrome without all the spying and tracking...

Comment: Yeah, Brave has it's *own* spying and tracking.